# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError in Java 8 MethodHandles.Lookup

Tags: java, java-8

The method below builds supplier, it's invokes successfully and cache the supplier into hashmap. But if I register packet from another classloader (from module), `Supplier#get` throws

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.

```
    private Supplier<DefinedPacket> buildSupplier(@NonNull Class<? extends DefinedPacket> packetClass)
        throws Throwable {
    MethodHandles.Lookup lookup = MethodHandles.lookup();
    MethodType invokedType = MethodType.methodType(Supplier.class);
    CallSite callSite = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(lookup,
            "get",
            invokedType,
            MethodType.methodType(Object.class),
            lookup.findConstructor(packetClass, MethodType.methodType(void.class)),
            MethodType.methodType(String.class));
    return (Supplier<DefinedPacket>) callSite.getTarget().invoke();
}
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: you should try to pass `MethodHandles.Lookup` as argument of this function - so you can provide lookup that is bound to that other class loader. Or try to use `MethodHandles.lookup().in(packetClass);`

Comment: “from module”? So this is rather a `[java-9]` question instead of `[java-8]`? Besides that, `MethodType.methodType(String.class)` does not look correct for a `Supplier<DefinedPacket>`…